# Verify if Propositions hold or not

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I want to show wether or not these two propositions hold or not.
The first one is that $$\forall x\exists y(xy>0\implies y>0)$$
For this one I noticed that hen $y=0$ it doesn’t hold. But I’m confused wether or not I am done proving or not.

---

The second one is 
$$\lnot\forall x\exists y(xy\ge  x^2)$$
For this one, I noticed that if you set $x=y$, then you get $y^2\ge y^2$. Once again, I’m not sure how this helps.

I would appreciate any help on these two propositions.

Comment: In the first, you say that $y=0$, but what is $x$? In any case, whatever $x$ might be, $y=0$ doesn't work: $(xy>0\to y>0)$ is TRUE for $y=0$, "vacuously". For the second, note that it's equivalent to $\exists x\forall y(xy<x^2)$. Suppose there is such an $x$; which value of $y$ makes the inner statement false? (you already found it)

Comment: @BrianO I don't quite understand what you mean for the first one. For the second one, I noticed that, but I don't know how I would be able to prove it.

Comment: Any statement $A\to B$ is true if $A$ is false. (This is essential to mathematical reasoning, you really have to know this.) If $y=0$ then $xy>0$ is false.

Comment: Re the second, based on what you wrote in the question it isn't clear that you did notice what I said in my previous comment. You write "$y^2\ge y^2$", which suggests that you failed to negate $xy\ge y^2$.

Comment: @BrianO Can you please post your answer, I'm still not understanding the first one

Comment: I posted an answer, giving two different proofs of the first sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. $\forall x\exists y(xy>0\to y>0)$ is *true*.

   (*by contradiction*) Let's prove that the negation of 1. is impossible. Negating 1. gives
   $$
     \exists x \forall y (xy>0 \land y\le 0).\tag{not-1}
   $$
   Suppose $x$ is such that (not-1) holds. Then $\forall y (xy>0 \land y\le 0)$, so $\forall y (y\le 0)$ — that is, every $y$ is less than $0$, which is false. So (not-1) is false, thus 1. is true.

   (*direct proof*) Note that $p\to q$ is equivalent to $\neg p\lor q$, so 1. is equivalent to
   $$
   \exists x\forall y(xy\le 0 \lor y>0).
   $$
   Clearly, for all $y$, it's true that $(y\le 0 \lor y>0)$, or equivalently, $(1y\le 0 \lor y>0)$. So $\forall y(1y\le 0 \lor y>0)$. Now we see that $x=1$ satisfies $\forall y(xy\le 0 \lor y>0)$, so 1. follows.
2. $\neg\forall x\exists y(xy\ge x^2)$ is false.

   The sentence is equivalent to
   $$
   \exists x\forall y(xy<x^2).\tag{2'}
   $$
   Suppose $x$ is such that $\forall y(xy<x^2)$. Then in particular it must be true for $y=x$, so we have $x^2 = xy < x^2$, which is ridiculous. So (2') can't be true, thus the equivalent 2. is false.

Comment: Good — I guess it "clicked", and you get it now :)

Answer (score 0):

For the first proposition, showing that it doesn't work for $y = 0$ isn't a counterexample that disproves the statement. The qualifiers at the start of the statement, $\forall{x} \exists{y} $, mean that for every $x$, there exists at least one $y$ such that $xy \gt 0 \implies y \gt 0$. A counterexample that properly disproves the proposition would be some $x$ for which there doesn't exist *any* $y$ such that

$xy \gt 0 \implies y \gt 0$.

For the second proposition, it's easiest to transform the statement, as suggested by BrianO's comment. We have:

$\neg \forall{x}  \exists{y} (xy \geq x^2) \iff \exists{x} \neg  \exists{y} (xy \geq x^2) \iff \exists{x} \forall{y} \neg(xy \geq x^2) \iff \exists{x} \forall{y} (xy \lt x^2)$

To disprove this, we have to show that for all $x$, there exists some $y$ such that $xy \geq x^2$.

Comment: Yes, but how would I show this? I can't think of any counterexamples.

Comment: @user308840 Look, suppose $x$ is such that $\forall y (xy<x^2)$. You already mention a counterexample $y$ at the end of your question.

Comment: @BrianO So basically, if I rewrite the to the form $\exists x\forall y(xy< x^2)$ and then set $y=x$ which means that $x^2<x^2$, then this proves it by contradiction?

Comment: How could it not. It seems you're not sure what "proof" means. // Yes. The statement says that there's some $x$ such that for all $y$ BlahBlah($y$). If it's false that BlahBlah($x$), then you've shown that "for all $y$ BlahBlah($y$)" is false. Since $x$ was any supposed "witness", you can conclude that there's no such $x$ — that is, the whole statement is false.

Comment: @DylanSp How would I prove the first one?

Comment: @user308840 If $x$ is negative, what must $y$ be so that $xy \gt 0$?